# Jstree and angularJS using promise

Tags: angularjs, jstree

I lost two  days trying to solve this problem by myself, but I  give up.  pleaseee help .
i want to load  my tree using jstree and promise AngularJS

but I keep getting this error:

Uncaught Neither data nor ajax settings supplied.

i can see im my html page jsut the pluging loading and no result :(
y'll  find in thi  link my code .

http://plnkr.co/edit/kDjFCa4x6Ghyb3pwghXc?p=preview

Thank you very much :)

Comment: "this is my code - fix it" - is a very bad way to find help here. at least try to create plunker or jsfiddle for those who will try to solve your issue and let us know, what exactly doesn't work and what have you tried to fix that.

Comment: @OZ_ i upadte my post. thks

Comment: your example doesn't work (libraries are not found), check it. As variant - use http://cdnjs.com as source of libraries.

Comment: I found that "Neither data nor ajax settings supplied" is response from jsTree library.

Comment: i agree with you that the response is from jsTree library.( and i don't have any idea how to solve his problem ) But i want know also is my angular's code correct ??

Comment: currently I see in console `scope---------------[object Object]` so your plunker works, just few files with data are missing. And finally I see that error warning, and I see path "test.data["title"]= "file:/home/workspace/Integration/" - you can't get file by this way (javascript can't access files on user's computer).  I think that moving copies of data files to plunker can help you to see where is source of error.

Comment: "file:/home/workspace/Integration/" is just a string, i'm not trying to acces  files on user's computer). i update my plunker , thks @OZ_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing with your code, I got this: http://plnkr.co/edit/JfTVNdQnaGZV01wyQHtn
changes: third argument of scope.$watch to true, setting "json_data" to

```
"json_data" :{
 "data":scope.jstree.data
}
```

(looks strange, but it's quirks of jsTree)

Comment: Yes, it's quiks of jstree, thank youuuuuu very much @OZ_ ,i spent more than 2 days to get the solution.